# How to have JPA leverage the benefits of partitioning on an Oracle database table

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have an oracle database(not a cluster) running on a dedicated server. The data in some of the tables crosses well beyond a few million, resulting in slow running queries. We recently decided to go with horizontal partitioning on a few tables. We created interval range partitions on a field, ADD_DATE. For simplicity, we can say that a partition spans entries that were added in a month. So all entries for Jan 2017 go into one partition, and so on. Given the two queries below:

1. `select * from orders where order_id={some_order_id}`
2. `select * from orders where add_date={some_date} and order_id={some_order_id}`

Understandably, when I run these directly on SQL Developer, the second query is significantly faster. My question is, is there a way for us to make JPA use add_date to narrow down the search space?
I am aware that Eclipselink provides a @Partitioned and @RangePartitioning annotations. How can this help me leverage my partitioning on ADD_DATE column when using the below 3 types of queries:

1. JPA api methods. e.g. `em.find(obj, ObjClass.class)`
2. JPQL queries e.g. `em.createQuery(select s from suppliers where supplier_id=:id)`
3. Native queries executed through Hibernate/Eclipselink e.g. `em.createNativeQuery(select * from log where order_id=?)`

Any help in aiding my understanding is much appreciated. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for formatting the question properly. Will make sure to adhere from the next post on. :)